# Turning image path into data suitable for storing in MySQL Blob

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have a file in the location

```
$imgloc = "../images/bg.jpg";
```

How do I:

1. Load the image into a PHP variable
2. Turn into a BLOB suitable data type (if not already)
3. Insert into MySQL (If any additional steps are needed)

Comment: why don't you store only the path in your DB ?

Comment: That is an alternative way but I'd prefer to store directly into DB. I've looked it up and both methods have their pros and cons. I've decided to go with storing as a BLOB.

Answer (score 2):

```
$imgHandler = fopen (imgloc, 'rb'); // open with read binary
$imgContent = fread ($imgHandler , filesize ($imgloc));
// now you can store $imgContent in MySQL
```

Comment: Although not neccesary to answer this question, i'd like to add, that when encoding the data using `base64_encode`you get two things: the ability to store the binary data as simple string (e.g. `varchar` etc.) and also you can render the image in html using `<img src="data:image/[IMG_TYPE];base64,[BASE64_DATA_STRING]">`. Halayem's answer is sufficient tho.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm struggling to get it to insert into my MySQL database. I'm doing "INSERT INTO image('img') VALUES('" . $imgContent . "');"

Comment: do you have an issue with that ?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't insert. If I replace the `VALUES('" . $imgContent . "');` variable with random 0s and 1s it inserts just fine?